# Can magnetic-molecular dynamics be used to study the macroscopic rotation of a lattice? Such as the Einstein-De Haas effect and the Barnett effect

Tags: rotational-dynamics, angular-momentum, molecular-dynamics

When applying molecular dynamics, it is generally assumed that the equilibrium positions of the atoms are fixed, in which case the calculated displacements of the atoms are the displacements with respect to their equilibrium positions. If one wants to study the macroscopic rotation (i.e., all atoms rotating at the same angular velocity) of a crystal (e.g., a ferromagnetic disk), wouldn't one have to assume that the equilibrium positions of the atoms can also rotate around the origin of the coordinates.

Comment: It'd probably just be easier to work in a rotating reference frame and add in the appropriate forces (centrifugal, Coriolis, etc.)

Comment: I can understand the question, but why the reference to the Einstein-de-Haas effect? I don't see any connection to the microscopic atomic or molecular structure of the material.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I decided to consider both forces as you said.

Comment: Because here the overall rotation of the system is due to the EdH effect. My doubt is that when an atom rotates around its equilibrium position and around the center of mass of the system as a whole at the same time, how should one study the dynamics of these two rotations separately?